# Make ordered numbers from intersections using Geopandas?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I'm have two shapefiles: points and line. What I want to do is to check how many points are intersecting with/belonging to a single line feature, then I'd like to order the points based on the line feature they belong too, here is the code I wrote it keeps making empty or wrong numbers. Any suggestion would be appreciated ! here is my code:

```
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

for line in duct.geometry:
   line_length = line.length  

   # Intersect the line with the points
   line_points = points.intersection(line)

   # Iterate through the intersected points
   for i, p in enumerate(line_points, start=1):
       points = points.append({'number': i, 'geometry': p}, ignore_index=True)
```

I tried the code above but it keeps giving me empty or wrong numbers.